# Galleon v0.9b - how to delegate XTZ to multiple bakers from a Manager Address?

Tags: galleon

I have asked the following questions to Galleon Support Team but their reply completely missed my points and unhelpful.  Therefore, I seek help here.

Basic assumption:  I have a Ledger Nano connected to my Galleon v. 0.9b (thus NOT a file wallet).  Then my questions are as follows:

After the Babylon upgrade, there have been many confusions as to the introduction of the post Babylon upgrade format on Galleon.  For once and all, I would like to get how to operate Galleon straight (I have about 8K XTZ on my Galleon wallet).

Question 1: How to create a new Manager Address/newly delegate to multiple bakers

I understand that from now onward, one can delegate only from a Manager Address.  Currently my Manager Address is delegated to one baker.  Please tell me in plain English how to create a new Manager Address/Manger Account so that I can delegate part of my XTZ holdings to a different baker from the one that my currently existing Manger Address is delegated to?

Question 2* How to send XTZ from a existing KT1 account to another address (like an exchange to sell XTZ on that exchange)

I have one KT1 account that has about 4000XTZ which is delegated to a baker.  Could you tell me step by step how to send those XTZ in this KT1 account to an external address.  Now all I can see is “Transactions” and “Manage Delegation” tabs.    I suppose you can send XTZ to an external account only from a Manager Address/Account.  So what should I do?

Should I click first 1) “Withdraw” under “ Manage Delegation”, secondly 2) type in the amount that I want to take out of the delegated XTZ for sending off to an external account, thirdly 3)Press “Invoke”.

Then, my confusion is that this “undelegated XTZ” would go straight to the Manager Address.  I see “Send” tab under “Manager Address”.  Should I use that Send function.  If so, I would not have to undelegated or anything.  Just type the amount of XTZ that I want to send to an external address and of course input the external address that I want send XTZ to? In connection with my Question 1, what if I have multiple Manager Addresses (if I can creat multiple manager addresses, how could I know which manager address my XTZ withdrawn from my KT1 account would go into?

======

Many thanks in anticipation for your help.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1):

1- Your Tz1 address is the implicit account and Kt1 addresses are smart contracts.
Each implicit account can only delegate to one baker. Ledger supports having several implicit accounts, however Galleon does not.

2- In order to withdraw your XTZ from your KT1 account, click on the ''manage delegation'' tab and on ''withdraw''. Enter the amount that you would like to withdraw from this address. Once confirmed, it will show up in your manager address after being deducted from your KT1 address. From there you can send your funds to an exchange or a different wallet. keep in mind this will affect your delegation. If you move funds out, your balance will decrease which in turn will decrease your earnings. Same goes for adding funds. Your rewards will increase because you are holding more coins.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  On Q1, as I understand from Galleon Support Team, it seems that I would have to create multiple separate Galleon wallets if I want to delegate to multiple bakers.  What a nightmare....

Answer (score 0):

you would have to create kt1 addresses via a smart contract and delegate with those on a per-contract basis. I'm still waiting for someone to answer my question as to how to make these smart contract Kt1 addresses... Hopefully someone answers here